# How to align element to bottom of parent and fit text contents

Tags: html, css

I have a image with a overlay of words over it. Now I want the box containing these words to be aligned to bottom of the image and being increased when more words are added to that box. So box increase height from bottom:

```css
.mini-pic-small-style {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    float: left;
    height: 272px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .mini-pic-small-style.draw-shadow img {
        max-height: 250px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .games_img_interests {
        background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        color: #444446;
        left: -10px;
        position: relative;
        top: -70px;
        width: 106%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mini-pic-small-style draw-shadow">
    <a title="Benutzerprofil" target="_parent" href="index.php">
    <img src="http://dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/3185/thumbs/1428834630.jpg" class="first-row-image-img"></a>                            
    <!-- Show interests -->
    <div class="games_img_interests"> Computer, England, Fahrradfahren,Fotografie, Freunde treffen, Kaffee, Kamera, Kino, Laufen, London,Musik     hören, Reisen, Schwimmen, Wandern.
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.mini-pic-small-style {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    float: left;
    height: 272px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; /* <------------ needed for child positioning */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* <------------ keeps padding inside 100% width */
}
.mini-pic-small-style.draw-shadow img {
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.games_img_interests {
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #444446;
    position: absolute; /* <------------ allows bottom alignment */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mini-pic-small-style draw-shadow">
    <a title="Benutzerprofil" target="_parent" href="index.php">
    <img src="http://dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/3185/thumbs/1428834630.jpg" class="first-row-image-img"></a>                            
    <!-- Show interests -->
    <div class="games_img_interests"> Computer, England, Fahrradfahren,Fotografie, Freunde treffen, Kaffee, Kamera, Kino, Laufen, London,Musik     hören, Reisen, Schwimmen, Wandern.
    </div>
    </div>
```